# mySQL creating a view with all combinations of rows from 2 tables out of 3?

Tags: mysql

First of all, here is the sqlfiddle I made: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d06c

I have 3 tables, project, document_template, and project_document.

- The project table contains a project id and a name.
- The document template table contains a document template id and a name for the template.
- The project document table contains an id, and a project id and document template id associated with it, as well as a date when it was sent.

I'm trying to create a view that contains all combinations of project ids and document template ids, which I can do easily with a

```
CROSS JOIN
```

However, after that I would like to add an additional column to the view named 'last_sent' that contains the latest date at which a template is used with a project, and in order to do that it has to look at the information in the project_document table.

I've included an example in comments at the bottom of the sqlfiddle code to show how it should look.

I've tried adding different left joins to the end of the view query but can't seem to get it to show how I want it to. :(

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SETUP:

basically get your Cartesian Product.. then join the project_id's and document_template_id's to the most recent date.. that date needs to be in a separate select with the id for the project and doc_temp so that you can join it appropriately.. finally use coalesce on the date so that when theres null values you put in a blank

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    t1.project_id , t1.document_template_id , COALESCE(t.last_sent, ' ') AS last_sent
FROM
(   SELECT p.project_id, dt.document_template_id
    FROM project p, document_template dt
    GROUP BY project_id, document_template_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(   SELECT project_id, document_template_id, MAX(sent_on) AS last_sent 
    FROM project_document
    GROUP BY document_template_id
) t ON t.project_id = t1.project_id 
    AND t.document_template_id = t1.document_template_id;
```

## OUTPUT:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| project_id   | document_template_id     | last_sent           |
+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| 1            | 1                        |                     |
| 1            | 2                        | 2014-08-12 10:00:23 |
| 1            | 3                        | 2014-07-11 08:12:40 |
| 2            | 1                        |                     |
| 2            | 2                        |                     |
| 2            | 3                        |                     |
+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d06c/52)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
    p.project_id,
    dt.document_template_id,
    MAX(pd.sent_on) AS last_sent
FROM project p
CROSS JOIN document_template dt
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_document pd 
     ON p.project_id=pd.project_id 
     AND dt.document_template_id=pd.document_template_id
GROUP BY p.project_id, dt.document_template_id
ORDER BY p.project_id, dt.document_template_id
```

If you want empty instead null use `COALESCE(MAX(pd.sent_on), '') AS last_sent` instead

When you use aggregate functions as MAX, you should point group target by `GROUP BY` clause. Else you will have only one returned row.